# Using '@' sign in input doesn't alter table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a line of code that alters a table by adding a column for an email. For some reason, whenever there is an `@` in the string, it doesn't update the table. Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
mysqli_query($dbcon,"ALTER TABLE ipList ADD ".$userName." VARCHAR(100)");
```

It works fine if I type in something like `test` in my input field, but if I did `test@example.com` , the table doesn't update. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using backticks with your variable,

```
mysqli_query('ALTER TABLE  `iplist` Add `'.$username.'` VARCHAR( 100 ) ');
```

Comment: OH! Duh!!!! lol. Should have realized the field value wasn't being encapsulated.  Sorry, it's been awhile since I've had to use raw SQL in PHP. CodeIgniter (ActiveRecord) for-the-win! :D

Answer (score 3):

First of all, why are you adding a new column to a table based on a user name? Usually having to change the data model in a program is a sign of something being wrong with the database design.

You can use backticks to quote the names of tables an columns that include unusual characters such as white space, `@` or `.`:

```
mysqli_query("ALTER TABLE ipList ADD `$userName` VARCHAR(100)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $userName);
mysqli_query($dbcon,"ALTER TABLE ipList ADD ".$userName." VARCHAR(100)");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

(Be careful with that, might want to look into SQL injection; because dumping params directly into an SQL string, is never recommended)

Comment: Hm, thanks for the answer, but this didn't work either. I even tried using `stripslashes($userName)` before doing `mysqli_real_escape_string()`...